# wp_register_script not working

Tags: php, wordpress

That's not my first wordpress plugin but I don't know why I'm not able to make wp_register_script to work.

If I just echo the script works (so I checked that the url is correct) and I don't care about deps because the code is native JS.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Calculated to paypal
Version: 1.1
Description: Update Paypal Buy now button
Author: Antocorr
Author URI: http://example.com
*/
function calculated_to_paypal_script()
{
    $jsurl = plugins_url() . '/calculated-to-paypal/js/app.js';
    wp_register_script( 'ccp-url', $jsurl, false, NULL, 'all');

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'calculated_to_paypal_script' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing following line of code

```
$jsurl = plugins_url() . '/calculated-to-paypal/js/app.js';
```

as follows;

```
$jsurl = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/calculated-to-paypal/js/app.js
```

or enqueue or register script as follows;

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/calculated-to-paypal/js/app.js' );
```

register

```
wp_register_script( 'myscript', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/calculated-to-paypal/js/app.js' );
```

**Full code for function**

use your function as follows;

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "myscript");
function myscript() { 
wp_register_script('myjs', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/calculated-to-paypal/js/app.js',
                    array ('jquery', 'jquery-ui'), //try without these first, if fails try adding this line 
                    false, false);
wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
```

}

Comment: Hi, it only works by wp_enqueue_script directly (your third solution). but i get "Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in functions.php on line 4139"

Comment: probably, your code may need some dependency, try to add  (array' dependency' ) , and version to false, and try something like follows. **`add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "myscript");
function myscript() { 
    wp_register_script('myjs', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/calculated-to-paypal/js/app.js',
                        array ('jquery', 'jquery-ui'), //try without these first, if fails try adding this line 
                        false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
      
}`**